# Why don't dconf-editor and dconf list show the same directory structure?

Tags: dconf

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 with Unity 2D. If I open the dconf-editor and navigate through:

org > gnome > gedit > plugins

I see a directory for plugins and the keys: drawspaces, externaltools, pythonconsole, terminal and time.

If, from a gnome-terminal, I enter the command `dconf list /org/gnome/gedit/plugins/` I see the key active-plugins and the directory filebrowser.

Why don't I see the same thing with both dconf-editor and dconf list???

Answer (score 3):

The command-line tool `dconf` seems to show only those settings which are actually set in the database (so they are different from the default), whereas `dconf-editor` shows all possible settings. You will notice that the button "Set to Default" in `dconf-editor` is greyed out for those settings which are not shown by `dconf`.