# How to search dconf for keys or values?

Tags: dconf

I loaded `dconf-editor`. There is no menu, but I did discover that you can press `Ctrl+F` and enter a search term.

However, I do not know what `Ctrl+F` actually searches. When I enter a term (e.g. `panel` or `unity-greeter`), I receive no results.

I have also tried `gsettings` at the command line, but with no luck whatever options I have tried; I must be doing it incorrectly.

How do I search for a specific key or value within dconf?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

First, the search function in `dconf-editor` searches only among those things which are directly visible on screen or reachable by scrolling (note that the search field looks just like the one in other applications like Nautilus).

I know of no other graphical tool you could use. So you probably need to use the command line tool `dconf` (also from the package `dconf-tools`).

Specifically for search recursively through the whole database (including keys and values) I would use this command:

```
dconf dump / | grep SEARCH-TERM
```

`dump` basically gives you the whole database in an "Windows-Ini-File"-like format. For browsing through the database, use `dconf list /PATH`.

As you've mentioned `gsettings`, the equivalent search command there is:

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep SEARCH-TERM
```

However, this may not be what you want (for a search for `unity`, this gives completely different results for me). Not sure what database is used here.

***Edit:*** After reading [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138025/why-dont-dconf-editor-and-dconf-list-show-the-same-directory-structure/172699#172699), I noticed that `dconf` shows you only the settings which are actually set in the database, not all possible settings like `dconf-editor`. Apparently you can use `gsettings list-schemas` to give you all possible settings.

Comment: To add your answer, Phillip, I used `less` with search instead of `grep`, so that I could find the sub-settings: `dconf dump / | less`. Thank you.

Comment: i wonder why I can access Guake preferences (/apps/Guake/) from dconf-editor/dconf and not using gsettings.

Answer (score 0):

```
dconf read <KEY>
```

For example, to read the current wallpaper picture filename:

```
dconf read /org/mate/desktop/background/picture-filename
```

For a list of keys
    dconf dump / > dconf.dump

You can then examine the text file `dconf.dump` for the key you want to query. To construct the wallpaper query look to here :

```
[org/mate/desktop/background]
color-shading-type='vertical-gradient'
primary-color='rgb(88,145,188)'
picture-options='zoom'
picture-filename='yourwallpaperpicturefile.png'  <<< 
secondary-color='rgb(60,143,37)'
```