# Gnome 3.10 sharing desktop --- how to configure the security type for VNC?

Tags: gnome, vnc

**The facts:** I had a configuration for sharing my desktop that worked till the recent update of Gnome desktop to use sgnome-shell 3.10. I used to connect to my machine form a Windows one using TightVNC and it worked flawlessly till yesterday (2014-19-1).

Now the connection from the Windows side is failing ([full log in pastebin](http://pastebin.com/dUg2fHdB)) with this error:

[image: tightvnc error]

Which digging the log it is:

```
[ 5872/ 6448] 2014-01-20 12:11:18:247   List of security type is read
[ 5872/ 6448] 2014-01-20 12:11:18:247 : Security Types received (1): Unknown type (18)
[ 5872/ 6448] 2014-01-20 12:11:18:247   Selecting auth-handler
[ 5872/ 6448] 2014-01-20 12:11:18:247 + RemoteViewerCore. Exception: No security types supported. Server sent security types, but we do not support any of their.
```

The "sharing" part is configured as it should, as you can see here:

[image: sharing-settings]

**The diagnosis:** It seems that the update changed the security type to a new one not known by tightVNC (it happened in the past).

**The Question:** until TightVNC (and the rest of the world) [catches up](https://sourceforge.net/p/vnc-tight/feature-requests/693/), is it possible to configure the internal VNC server to use the previous Security Type?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Real solution**: I am now using [SSVNC](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/ssvnc.html) on the windows machine and [x11vnc](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers) on the linux server. Works with bVNC on android too. You need a bit of expertise to make it work, so terse instruction here:

On Linux (follow the instruction that x11vnc is giving you, is verbose but worth reading):

```
x11vnc -storepasswd
x11vnc -forever -repeat -usepw -ssl -autoport 6000
```

(you will have to put the last one in one of your login startup scripts, or whatever. Do not use a passphrase on the generated SSL certificate. I am using port 6000 to not mess with vino).

On Windows: Install the binary client [from here](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/ssvnc.html#download).

Connect and enjoy a (slowish...) encrypted connection.

**Partial answer:** (posted for sake of helping other people, **NOT RECOMMENDED**); I hope there will be other answers to the question --- I will mark this answer as the right one as there are no solution by now).

The problem surfaced when the Vino project decided to switch to [require encryption by default](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=728267#c3) --- unfortunately, the only kind of encryption supported by the `vino` server (type 18) is **not** supported by most of the Windows, Android, and iOS viewer. For what I know, only the Linux-based `vinagre` viewer supports it.

I have reported a bug to the Vino project, [both upstream](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=728267) and in [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vino/+bug/1281250)   about this issue; look there for more details. Basically, it seems that there is no sufficient developer power to implement more encryption types to the server (fair enough).

That means that you can go back to the previous, **unsafe** behavior 
by disabling encryption for the whole VNC layer by using `dconf-editor` like this:

[image: No Encryption for VNC]

**Big fat notice** that means that all what you type is **visible in clear** in the network. Passwords included.

I can do it because the connection is really through an encrypted SSH tunnel and there are no other local users on the remote machine --- but even in this case, if someone manage to get access to your machine, they can read all your secrets by sniffing 127.0.0.1...

Comment: If anyone else is looking for the key's location, it's under `org»gnome»desktop»remote-access`. Btw as soon as I changed this setting I could immediately connect to the box again.

Comment: Yes, it works --- but the connection will be not encrypted on the line, password included, so use it only in very safe networks. Having the options to use an old encryption would be safer.

Answer (score 10):

**One liner UNSAFE encryption turn off command for 16.04**

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/remote-access/require-encryption false
```

then TigerVNC and realvnc work from Windows.

As [Rmano](https://askubuntu.com/a/408375/52975) pointed out however, only do this if your connection is already encrypted on another layer.

Found with [`dconf dump`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169704/how-to-search-dconf-for-keys-or-values).

There is also a compatibility request on the TigerVNC side: https://github.com/TigerVNC/tigervnc/issues/307

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Use SSH to secure the unencrypted VNC session...

Disable the client unsupported default encryption requirement

`dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/remote-access/require-encryption false`

Disable listening on the default interface, use `lo` (loopback)

`dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/remote-access/network-interface lo`

Windows has the necessary commands to generate SSH keys, copy the ssh id to the vnc-tunnel account, and setup a port forward.

Example SSH port forwarding command

`ssh.exe -vvv -L 5900:127.0.0.1:5900 -N -i %USERPROFILE%/.ssh/id_vnc vnc-tunnel@linux.host`

Comment: Yes, but now another local user on the Linux machine can see the traffic from lo to the vino server unencrypted. If you are sure you are the only user on the Linux machine (can you? ) it's ok, and it's the solution I use --- read the last paragraph of my question.

Answer (score 0):

Quickly locate location to edit - start dconf-editor, type ctl f - type 5900 - press enter and the proper area to disable encryption is displayed. If multiple sections have 5900, press next to find next occurrence.

Comment: Yes --- if you read my answer and the question carefully, you'll see that I know how to disable encryption. I am asking if it's possible to **downgrade** the security algorithm to the previous used one! This answer is basically the same than mine, I do not understand it.