# What is the default VNC server included?

Tags: vnc

By default, there is an application installed in Ubuntu that allows for remote desktop connections over VNC. The application shows up with the name *Desktop Sharing* in the Unity dock.

What is the actual name of this default VNC application, assuming you wanted to start the graphical application from the terminal.

Comment: As a side note, I just realized Vino is installed by default on Ubuntu, but not on XUbuntu, however, if you are running the latter, a quick `sudo apt-get install vino` will solve that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The default VNC server is called [Vino](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vino). It's part of the GNOME project.
The Desktop Sharing app you see is `vino-preferences`. It doesn't have a man page that I can find, but the three programs of interest are:

1. `vino-preferences`
2. `vino-passwd`
3. `/usr/lib/vino/vino-server` (it's not in the PATH, in case you want to start it manually.)

Comment: Perfect, all and exactly what I needed!

Comment: +1; you can be interested in this too: http://askubuntu.com/questions/408365/gnome-3-10-sharing-desktop-how-to-configure-the-security-type-for-vnc (summary: you have to disable encryption for this to work with most windows or Mac clients; still valid or 14.04)

Comment: Does `vino-preferences` not exist anymore, or is my system messed up?