# What's the difference between RealVNC and x11vnc?

Tags: vnc

Specifically, what is easier (I assume RealVNC), safer, and faster? And any other general differences I should know about?

Comment: Not an answer because I don't know RealVNC, but you can find this Q&A interesting on the security side: http://askubuntu.com/questions/408365/gnome-3-10-sharing-desktop-how-to-configure-the-security-type-for-vnc

Comment: RealVNC, TightVNC, etc. are usually used like RDP on Windows, where you get your own separate X session when you connect.  X11VNC is more commonly used when you want to share an existing X session (e.g. so you can see/control what's going on on the desktop, including users logging in and out).

Comment: X11VNC Server is an app in the Ubuntu app store which allows RealVNC and TightVNC clients to connect. Is this question about that one? I use RealVNC and it's 'OK' but not 'Super' so far. It's paid though.