# Ubuntu: encrypted remote desktop server?

Tags: vnc, remote, remote-x-session

I need an encrypted remote desktop server for my ubuntu computer. Can someone tell me which package or programm should I install? But the connection must be encrypted!

Thank you very much.

Kind Regards

Comment: I would recommend `x11vnc` --- see http://askubuntu.com/questions/408365/gnome-3-10-sharing-desktop-how-to-configure-the-security-type-for-vnc

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's already installed. Vino. Open the 'Desktop Sharing' dialogue to configure it.

In Ubuntu 14.04 some people seem to have issues with getting Vino to work with encryption, if that is the case you can disable the encryption with: `gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false`

To still achieve encryption this way, you will have to run it through an SSH tunnel.

Here's a list of alternative options: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers

Comment: The problem with encryption is that the Vino encryption is understood almost only by vinagre (i.e., connecting from another Ubuntu/Linux machine). See  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vino/+bug/1281250 and http://askubuntu.com/questions/408365/gnome-3-10-sharing-desktop-how-to-configure-the-security-type-for-vnc. Doing what you say via ssh will still have the local connection unencrypted (not a problem is there are no other users on the machine)