# how to use remote desktop on ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, remote-desktop

I'm trying to use the "Remmina Remote Desktop" application that came with my Ubuntu 14.0.4 (64 bit) install to connect to another ubuntu desktop. 
But anytime, I try to connect, I get the message: "unable to connect to RDP server myservername".
I haven't "enabled" anything on the other server that I'm trying to connect to.  Do i need to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes:

1. you need to enable it.

   Go to the dash (or from a terminal) and run `vino-preferences` (It is called "Desktop sharing" in the dash):

   [image]

   It should be almost self-explicative.

and

2. The connection type is **VNC**, not RDP.

Read also [Gnome 3.10 sharing desktop --- how to configure the security type for VNC?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/408365/gnome-3-10-sharing-desktop-how-to-configure-the-security-type-for-vnc) --- contains important information.