# Ubuntu 16.04 escape key doesn't work in custom keyboard shortcut

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I've succeeded in mapping <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> to a custom binding (`gnome-system-monitor`).

When I change it to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd>, or  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd>, it does nothing. I looked through the other bindings mapped in keyboard preferences,and don't see any conflicting bindings.

Does anyone have any ideas about why this wouldn't work?

[image: image of the system keyboard preferences pane]

**Edit:** 
Thanks to @Redbob's suggestion, I found the existing binding for <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd> in the dconf-editor. No such luck with the plain <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd> binding: I also failed to find the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd> binding in the dconf settings on terminal (`gsettings list-recursively | grep "Escape"` as suggested by [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169704/how-to-search-dconf-for-keys-or-values)).

The conflict for <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd> came from this `dconf` entry:
`org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings cycle-panels ['<Control><Alt>Escape']`

Comment: install `dconf-editor`and go to `/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings`, probably you will find these shortcuts. If so, disable it there.