# Massive window I can't reduce in size - how to alter the "Program supplied minimum size"

Tags: xorg, window-manager, mate

I have a window (TortoiseHg) that whenever I open it is massive and I can't reduce the size.  I know about Alt-drag and I can (eventually) get to the edge, but I can't reduce the size.  If I run `xwininfo -all` the information includes:

```
xwininfo: Window id: 0x7200005 "TortoiseHg Workbench"

  Root window id: 0x192 (the root window) (has no name)
  Parent window id: 0x111e83a (has no name)
     1 child:
     0x720000e (has no name): ()  1x1+-1+-1  +4271+546

  Absolute upper-left X:  4272
  Absolute upper-left Y:  547
  Relative upper-left X:  1
  Relative upper-left Y:  28
  Width: 16383
  Height: 16383
  Depth: 24
  Visual: 0x139
  Visual Class: TrueColor
  Border width: 0
  Class: InputOutput
  Colormap: 0x7200004 (not installed)
  Bit Gravity State: NorthWestGravity
  Window Gravity State: NorthWestGravity
  Backing Store State: NotUseful
  Save Under State: no
  Map State: IsViewable
  Override Redirect State: no
  Corners:  +4272+547  --15135+547  --15135--15850  +4272--15850
  -geometry 16383x16383+4272+547

  ...

  Normal window size hints:
      Program supplied minimum size: 16383 by 16383
      Program supplied window gravity: StaticGravity
  No zoom window size hints defined

  No window shape defined
  No border shape defined
```

In particular this line:

```
      Program supplied minimum size: 16383 by 16383
```

I have tried:

- various ways of "maximising" the window, but none of them appear to have any effect.  (The same methods work on other windows fine.)
- removing `~/.config/TortoiseHg/` and re-running
- searching for files in `~/.cache/` or `~/.local/share/` for something that might cause this
- searched dconf and gconf [using this technique](https://askubuntu.com/a/172689/150) for any keys referring to `thg` or `tortoise` (case insensitive grep)
- running with `strace -f thg` looking for files it is opening that might set the minimum size

But I have not found anything that tells me where the "Program supplied minimum size" might be coming from.  Anyone know?

System details:

- I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with the Ubuntu Mate session, installed via the `ubuntu-mate-desktop` package.
- TortoiseHg is installed from the standard repos for 18.04 - no PPA etc.  The version reported by apt is 4.5.2-0ubuntu1 and `thg version` reports `TortoiseHg Dialogues (version 4.5.2), Mercurial (version 4.5.3)`
- The system is a laptop with 2 extra monitors attached via a USB-C docking station.  I have disabled HiDPI/scaling options.

Comment: what do `super`+`⬇` achieve? or `super` + `⬅`? with gnome-compliant windows such as your file browser or web browser it should make them fit half the screen or minimise. I'm going to try this app with ubuntu 19.04

Comment: no such issue : https://imgur.com/6pXsC8z I installed with `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:mercurial-ppa/releases -y && sudo apt update && sudo apt install tortoisehg -y` (had to add `--allow-unauthenticated` on update to run it succesfully for 19.04) hope you didn't build from source?

Comment: plus TortoiseHG respects gnome calls so win + arrow keys will dirrect the window to where you want it as expected. you really shouldn't have any issue making it reasonable sized. I used to run ubuntu 10 which was mate and I remember having had to bind the keys but sizing windows with these keyboard shortcuts was possible.

Comment: `super` + `⬅` does nothing to my tortoisehg window.  I've tested it with firefox and it works as expected.  I've tried various ways of "maximise" and none of them change the window size.  I'm pretty confused.

Comment: I did not build from source.

Comment: works for me :/ did you install with the same exact method as me?

Comment: what happens if you unplug the usb-C docking station and simply run it on the laptop's screen with no other screen?

Comment: @tatsu with the docking station unplugged, I still end up with the huge window size.  `xwininfo -all` still reports the same massive window size.

Comment: then it must be a mate issue. you should report it here https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issues/?kind=bug&status=open and here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mate